# Postgresql return text variable value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a function. Firstly I declared a variable When a result return I want to return variable result but I get an error. How can I solve?

Error

> ERROR:  column "exist-user" does not exist

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION savepromotionadmin(
     IN p_first_name character varying,
     IN p_last_name character varying,
     IN p_gsm character varying,
     IN p_email character varying,
     IN p_password character varying,
     IN p_level smallint)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$      
    DECLARE 
        result text;
        p_user_id bigint=(select id from user where email=p_email and gsm=p_gsm);
        p_check_user bigint=(select id from promotion_admin where email=p_email and gsm=p_gsm);
    BEGIN                   
        IF p_user_id is not null THEN
            IF p_check_user is null THEN            
                insert into promotion_admin(user_id, first_name, last_name, gsm, email, level, password)
                    values(p_user_id, p_first_name, p_last_name, p_gsm, p_email, p_level, md5(p_password));
                IF found THEN 
                    result:="added";                    
                    return result;
                ELSE 
                    result:="error";
                    return result;
                END IF;             
            ELSE 
                result:="exist-user";
                return result;
            END IF; 
        ELSE 
            result:="error";
            return result;
        END IF; 
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1000;
```

Comment: In SQL (and PL/pgSQL)  string constants have to be enclosed in single quotes `'` double quotes are for identifiers. Please read [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a data to a variable, you use the quote literal sign `'`. The quote indent sign `"` is for specify name of database object such as database name, table name, column name.

So, the code `result:="exist-user"` will assign data of column `exist-user` to variable `result`, and of course that column is not exists.

You can read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `"` are only for object-names (tables, columns etc.), for text you have to use `'`
change `result:="added";` to `result:='added';` and everything is fine